# How do I put my image inside my footer tag?

Tags: html, css, image, anchor, footer

I have a pretty basic problem with html & css. I've created a footer with a `<p>` tag and an `<li>` tag. Inside the `<li>` tag I have an image, this image however goes outside of the footer. **How can I make the image go inside the footer tag?**

**HTML**

```
<footer class="footer">
<p class="footerP">© Axel Halldin 2016 ©</p>
<li class="socialMedias"> <img class="facebook" src="facebook.jpg" href="https://www.facebook.com/axel.halldin1?fref=ts"/>
</li>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer{
background-color:#003366;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:90vw;
height:22.5vh;
float:right;
}

.footerP{
color:white;
font-family:FiraSans-Regular, sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
margin:0;
line-height:22.5vh;
}

.socialMedias{
float:right;
}

.facebook{
width:5vw;
height:10vh;
}
```

Comment: The image is inside the `footer` tag as the `li` is inside the footer tag

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Fixing that is usually a good first step. http://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: What is a List Item tag without an Ordered/Unordered list?

Comment: Where is ul/ol?? and if you are using float:right then use left to left element with clear.

Comment: try to play with this https://jsfiddle.net/cwy3kauw/

Comment: @Leothelion thanks mate

Comment: your welcome but still you need to learn alot...go with basics first.

Answer (score -2):

Add `overflow:auto;` in the .css as below:

```
.footer{
background-color:#003366;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:90vw;
height:22.5vh;
float:right;
overflow:auto;
}
```